# Searchview not is not Updating the recyclerview - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I'm trying to implement a search function..For that i used a searchview and implement a onQueryTextChange method but currently it filter data (Confirm with Log and display A Toast Message `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),temp.size()+toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();)`  (Here it will identify the recoreds based on user Input and display a Toast) but cannot update a recyclerview based on user Input and display a updated or filtered result..

```
        editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ArrayList<addAccount> dataholder = new ArrayList<>();

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(BillEntry.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.searchable_list_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Title");

                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                int height = (int) (displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.4);
                int width = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.9);
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);

                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));

                dialog.show();

                recyclerView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.listItems);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(dialog.getContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                adapter = new billEntryDialog(accounts);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                billEntryDialog adapter = new billEntryDialog(dataholder);

                displayAccountsFromJson(jsonData);

                SearchView search = dialog.findViewById(R.id.search);
                search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
//                        filter(newText.toString());
                        return true;
                    }
                });


                Button btnclosedialog = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
                btnclosedialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    void filter(String s){

        ArrayList<addAccount> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( addAccount item:accounts){

            if (item.getEdtAccountName().contains(s)){
                Log.d("Filter", "Filtered item: " + item.getEdtAccountName()); 
                temp.add(item);

            }
        }
        Log.d("SIzeddddd", "Filtered item: " + temp.size());(Log Filter item based on input)


        adapter.updatelist(temp);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

```
billEntryDialog.java (Adapter)

public class billEntryDialog extends RecyclerView.Adapter<billEntryDialog.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<addAccount> dataList;
    private ArrayList<addAccount> dataListFiltered;

    private FilterListener filterListener;

    public interface FilterListener {
        void onFilter(String query);
    }

    public billEntryDialog(ArrayList<addAccount> data) {
        this.dataList = data;
        this.dataListFiltered = data;
    }
    public void updatelist(ArrayList<addAccount> temp){
        this.dataList = temp;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setFilterListener(FilterListener listener) {
        this.filterListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_entry_account, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        addAccount data = dataListFiltered.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(data.getEdtAccountName());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (filterListener != null) {
                    filterListener.onFilter(data.getEdtAccountName());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataListFiltered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                String query = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                ArrayList<addAccount> tempFilteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                if (query.isEmpty()) {
                    tempFilteredList.addAll(dataList);
                } else {
                    for (addAccount item : dataList) {
                        if (item.getEdtAccountName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                            tempFilteredList.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }

                dataList=tempFilteredList;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = tempFilteredList;
                Log.d("Storeddddddddd", tempFilteredList.toString());
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                dataListFiltered.clear();
                dataListFiltered.addAll((List<addAccount>) results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName); // Replace with actual TextView ID
        }
    }
}
```

```
addAccount.java (Model) (Don't know if it's require here)

public class addAccount {

    private String edtAccountName,edtOpeningAmt,edtOpeningFine;

    public addAccount(String edtAccountName, String edtOpeningAmt, String edtOpeningFine) {
        this.edtAccountName = edtAccountName;
        this.edtOpeningAmt = edtOpeningAmt;
        this.edtOpeningFine = edtOpeningFine;
    }

    public addAccount(String edtAccountName) {
        this.edtAccountName = edtAccountName;
    }

    public String getEdtAccountName() {
        return edtAccountName;
    }

    public void setEdtAccountName(String edtAccountName) {
        this.edtAccountName = edtAccountName;
    }

    public String getEdtOpeningAmt() {
        return edtOpeningAmt;
    }

    public void setEdtOpeningAmt(String edtOpeningAmt) {
        this.edtOpeningAmt = edtOpeningAmt;
    }

    public String getEdtOpeningFine() {
        return edtOpeningFine;
    }

    public void setEdtOpeningFine(String edtOpeningFine) {
        this.edtOpeningFine = edtOpeningFine;
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re doing a lot in the on click listener, I think it would be better to have the recycler view already set up but empty ahead of time and then just add items to the adapter and notify dataset changed

Comment: First remove `billEntryDialog adapter = new billEntryDialog(dataholder);` which is below `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`.